# IdentityServer3: Some Claims not being returned from identity server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, katana, identityserver3

**Context:** 
I am using ASP.NET MVC with OWIN self host. Below are the rest of the configs/setup.

In my **Client**s in identity server (notice the **AllowedScopes** set):

```
public static class InMemoryClientSource
{
    public static List<Client> GetClientList()
    {
        return new List<Client>()
        {
            new Client()
            {
                ClientName = "Admin website",
                ClientId = "admin",
                Enabled = true,
                Flow = Flows.Hybrid,
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>()
                {
                    new Secret("admin".Sha256())
                },
                RedirectUris = new List<string>()
                {
                    "https://admin.localhost.com/"
                },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>()
                {
                    "https://admin.localhost.com/"
                },
                AllowedScopes = new List<string> {
                    Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    Constants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    Constants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    Constants.StandardScopes.Roles
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Here are the **Scopes**:

```
public static class InMemoryScopeSource
{
    public static List<Scope> GetScopeList()
    {
        var scopes = new List<Scope>();

        scopes.Add(StandardScopes.OpenId);
        scopes.Add(StandardScopes.Profile);
        scopes.Add(StandardScopes.Email);
        scopes.Add(StandardScopes.Roles);

        return scopes.ToList();
    }
}
```

In the **Identity Server**, here's how the server is configured. (Notice the **Clients** and **Scopes** are the ones provided above) :

```
var userService = new UsersService( .... repository passed here .... );

        var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
            .UseInMemoryClients(InMemoryClientSource.GetClientList())
            .UseInMemoryScopes(InMemoryScopeSource.GetScopeList());

        factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(resolver => userService);

        var options = new IdentityServerOptions()
        {
            Factory = factory,
            SigningCertificate = Certificates.Load(), // certificates blah blah
            SiteName = "Identity"
        };

        app.UseIdentityServer(options);
```

Finally, on the client web application side, this is how auth is set up:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            Authority = "https://id.localhost.com",
            ClientId = "admin",
            RedirectUri = "https://admin.localhost.com/",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://admin.localhost.com/",
            ResponseType = "code id_token token",
            Scope = "openid profile email roles",
            ClientSecret = "admin",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });
```

I have implemented a custom class for IUserService:

```
public class UsersService : UserServiceBase
{
    public UsersService( .... repository passed here .... )
    {
        //.... ctor stuff
    }

    public override Task AuthenticateLocalAsync(LocalAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        // var user = .... retrieved from database ..... 
        // ... auth logic ...

        if (isAuthenticated)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>();
            claims.Add(new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName));
            claims.Add(new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, user.LastName));
            claims.Add(new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Email, user.EmailAddress));
            context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult(user.Id.ToString(), user.EmailAddress, claims);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

As you see, the claims are passed in this line:

```
context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult(user.Id.ToString(), user.EmailAddress, claims);
```

When I try logging in to IdentityServer3, I can log in successfully to the client web application. **HOWEVER**, when I get the user claims, I don't see any identity claims. No **given_name**, **family_name**, and **email** claims. Screenshot below:

[image: As you can see, there are no given_name, family_name and email claims included.]

Anything I might have missed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your configuration looks fine. Silly I know, but are you sure the authenticated user has those claims?

Comment: Hey @ScottBrady, I assume they already have because I have added those claims to the context.AuthenticateResult (as you see on the sample code above for the custom UsersService implementation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found the solution for this problem.

First, I moved the creation of claims to the overridden GetProfileDataAsync (in my UserService class). Here's my implementation of it:

```
public override Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();

            UserInfo user = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Subject.Identity.Name))
                user = _facade.Get(context.Subject.Identity.Name);
            else
            {
                // get the sub claim
                var claim = context.Subject.FindFirst(item => item.Type == "sub");
                if (claim != null)
                {
                    Guid userId = new Guid(claim.Value);
                    user = _facade.Get(userId);
                }
            }

            if (user != null)
            {
                identity.AddClaims(new[]
                {
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.PreferredUserName, user.Username),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Email, user.EmailAddress)
                    // .. other claims
                });
            }

context.IssuedClaims = identity.Claims; //<- MAKE SURE you add the claims here
            return Task.FromResult(identity.Claims);
        }
```

Make sure that we pass the claims to the "context.IssueClaims" inside the GetProfileDataAsync() before returning the task.

And for those interested on how my AuthenticateLocalAsync() looks like:

```
var user = _facade.Get(context.UserName);
            if (user == null)
                return Task.FromResult(0);

            var isPasswordCorrect = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(context.Password, user.Password);
            if (isPasswordCorrect)
            {
                context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult(user.Id.ToString(), user.Username);
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
```

I raised a similar issue in IdentityServer3 GitHub project page that contains the explanation on why I encountered my issue. Here's the link:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1938

Comment: What does mean this part of code in method "GetProfileDataAsync": var claim = context.Subject.FindFirst(item => item.Type == "sub");
                if (claim != null)
                {
                    Guid userId = new Guid(claim.Value);
                    user = _facade.Get(userId);
                }

Comment: The method ""GetProfileDataAsync" is called twice and after first call is context.Subject.Identity.Name null, why is null - do you know?

Comment: @Jenan, to answer your first question, getting the "sub" (short for subject) claim is getting the username. nevermind the _facade part as that is my code for getting the user from the database.

As for your 2nd question, I have no idea why it is called twice. Perhaps you might want to go to the IdentityServer3 github discussion, someone might be able to help. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have some public code where you solved this problem in complete solution on github for example? :-)

Answer (score 6):

My solution was to add a list of claims to my scope configuration in order to return those claims. The wiki's documentation [here](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/scopesAndClaims.html) described it.

For an in-memory client all I did was something like this:

```
public class Scopes
{
    public static IEnumerable<Scope> Get()
    {
        return new Scope[]
        {
            StandardScopes.OpenId,
            StandardScopes.Profile,
            StandardScopes.Email,
            StandardScopes.Roles,
            StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
            new Scope
            {
                Name = "yourScopeNameHere",
                DisplayName = "A Nice Display Name",
                Type = ScopeType.Identity,
                Emphasize = false,
                Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
                {
                    new ScopeClaim("yourClaimNameHere", true),
                    new ScopeClaim("anotherClaimNameHere", true)
                }
            }
         };
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not using the identity server, however I am using the Windows Identity Foundation, which I believe is what IdentityServer uses. In order to access the claims I use:

`((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims`

Comment: Hi @rll, I have tried that but the claims are still what you can see in the screenshot in the question. Thanks anyway. :)